# How can I debug Dart Builders with breakpoints in WebStorm

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Dart uses the [build](https://github.com/dart-lang/build) package to generate code. What if you want to debug your own Builder or an existing one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of calling pub run build_runner  you can execute and debug the file build.dart which can be found here:

> .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/

[image]

To enter your command like serve as in pub run build_runner serve you can edit your debug configurations:

[image]

Put the command inside the field *Program arguments*:

[image]

Click *Apply* and start debugging again. Webstorm will interrupt when a breakpoint is reached.